# How to express the derivative of a function as its integral?

Tags: integration, derivatives, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

In the [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series#Definition), $${\displaystyle f(z)=\sum _{n=-\infty }^{\infty }a_{n}(z-c)^{n},}$$ the coefficients are the integrals $${\displaystyle a_{n}={\frac {1}{2\pi i}}\oint _{\gamma }{\frac {f(z)}{(z-c)^{n+1}}}\,dz.}$$
We know that the Taylor expansion and Laurent expansion, if both exist, are the same. However the coefficients in Taylor series are computed through **derivatives**, instead of integrals. Does this mean the derivative of $f(x)$ can be computed by some form of integral $\int \dots f(x)dx$?

From another point of view, in the language of *functional analysis*, or *geralized funtions / distributions*, a derivative is nothing but a linear operator. And a linear operator can always be viewed as an integral $\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = \int \beta(t, x)f(x) dx$ where $\beta(x)$ is a generalized function. However, this is just a formal rewriting which tells us nothing in essence. But the previous discussion suggesting that there might be an explicit relation between derivative and integral is what truly suprises me.

Comment: You might find it interesting to think of this in terms of [fractional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus), which allows you to use integration to define $\alpha$-th order derivatives for real $\alpha$. Note that the integral formula for the $\alpha$-th order derivative is typically undefined for positive integers $\alpha$, so if you'd like to get the actual derivative using an integral formula you would have to do so with some kind of limit

Comment: Yes, complex analytic functions can have their derivatves calculated by a variation of [Cauchy's Integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) $$f^{(n)}(c)=\frac {n!}{2\pi i}\oint _\gamma\frac {f(z)}{(z-c)^{n+1}}\,dz$$where $\gamma$ is any simple closed curve around $c$ such that $t$ is analytic inside it. Compare that to your formula and you see where it came from, with the only exception being that $f$ is not analytic at $c$ itself in the Laurent series. That comes from a further development of the same theory.